# USB keyboard acting strange with MacBook Pro

Tags: keyboard

I have a Cooler Master Storm USB keyboard.  I have plugged it in to my new MacBook Pro.  The OS took me through the keyboard setup screen, and 'recognized' the keyboard as a standard US one.  Some keys work, other keys do strange things.  When I press <kbd>c</kbd>, it types a c after the cursor, instead of before.  When I type <kbd>e</kbd>, it types an e along with a space after it.  Is it possible that this particular keyboard will not work with Mac OS X?

Comment: Have you verified it works correctly under Windows? It's important to ascertain this as it will save a lot of Mac troubleshooting if it turns out to simply be a defective keyboard.

Comment: @ScunnerDarkly - It does not work correctly in a Windows Parallels VM.  I don't have bootcamp Windows installed.  On my PC, the keyboard works fine.

Comment: Assuming I'm looking at the correct model of CM keyboard, I wonder if the NKRO mode is causing issues as it's not supported by OS X. The manual suggests there are two rollover modes, 6-key and full NKRO. Have you tried changing the rollover mode?

Comment: @ScunnerDarkly You sir deserve a Nobel Prize.  Please put this as an answer.  Switching NKRO mode fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad it sorted your problem, I've added an actual answer below.

Comment: I came from Google with the problem on the Quick-Fire TK keyboard. The shortcut to enable 6 key roll-over is FN+6+Esc, and to enable n-key-rollover is Fn+n+esc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else with this issue...

Referring to the user manual for the Cooler Master Storm USB keyboard, check the **N-Key Roll Over** mode (NKRO) as OS X doesn't support NKRO.

Comment: This link was very helpful: https://landing.coolermaster.com/faq/quick-fire-tk-key-commands/ (I have a TK version but basic idea is the same)